Dynamic update of plot in Matplotlib generating strange lines
I'm trying use dynamically add rectangles to a plot using Matplotlib but some weird lines are showing up in the plot.

My grid is a class with init and an update function to add new rectangle shapes to the plot
class GridDisplay:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize and configure the plot

    def UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords(self, layerID, newData):
        # update the plot with a new rectangle

The definition of the functions are shown in the code snippet below
def UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords(self, layerID, newData):
        
        x0 = newData[0]
        x1 = newData[2]
        y0 = round(newData[1], 6)
        y1 = round(newData[3], 6)
        
        height = round(y1 - y0, 6)
        width = round(x1 - x0, 6)
    
        y = y0

        x = x0
        
        self.rectangles.append((x, y, width, height))
        
        self.graph.remove()

        rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, edgecolor='yellow', facecolor=layerID, lw=1)

        self.ax.add_patch(rectangle)

        self.graph = self.ax.plot(self.rectangles)[0]

def __init__(self):
        
        ySize = 15
        xSize = 25
        xStart = -6
        yStart = -6
        xEnd = 5
        yEnd = 5

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(xSize, ySize))
        
        # Set axis limits
        self.ax.set_ylim( yStart, yEnd)
        self.ax.set_xlim(xStart, xEnd)
        
        # Change major ticks to show every 0.5
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
        self.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
        
        # Change minor ticks to show every 0.1
        self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(0.1))
        self.ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(0.5))
        
        # Turn grid on for both major and minor ticks and style minor slightly
        # differently.
        self.ax.grid(which='major', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle='--')
        self.ax.grid(which='minor', color='#CCCCCC', linestyle=':')
        
        
        # Set labels and title
    
        self.ax.set_xlabel('h')
    
        self.ax.set_ylabel('v')
    
        self.ax.set_title('S-Cell Routing grid')
    
        # Set grid
    
        self.ax.grid(True)
        
        self.rectangles = []
        
        self.graph = self.ax.plot(self.rectangles)[0]

The UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords function is called from another package which simply specifies the bound coordinates of the rectangle (x0, y0, x1, y1) as shown in the snippet below
self.gridDisplay.UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords(layerID, (startX, startY, endX, endY))
The layerID parameter is used to specify the colour of the rectangle and is not so important to the problem
The image shown is generated from the code below which demonstrates the problem.
import bin.ui.display as GridDisplay


gridDisplay = GridDisplay()

startX = -5
startY = -5

for i in range(1, 6):
    
    layer = str('Metal') + str(i)
    
    newData = (startX + round(i*0.2, 6), startY + round(i*0.5, 6), startX + round(i*0.6, 6), startY + round(i*0.7, 6))
    
    
    gridDisplay.UpdatePlotWithBoundboxCoords(layer, newData)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to figure out why the random lines are plotted.
I've looked up the documentation and posts on dynamically ploting shapes with Matplotlib but none on the solutions seem to work.
By the way, I also enabled the interactive mode for Matplotlib plt.ion()
Thanks and kind regards.
Update
What worked for me was to change the graph assignment in the last line of code in the UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords function from self.graph = self.ax.plot(self.rectangles)[0] to self.graph = self.ax.add_patch(rectangle)

The strange lines are caused by calling self.ax.plot(self.rectangles) in function UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords(). ax.plot() expects x and y coordinates as parameters to draw a curve, while you're giving a list of lists with [x,y,width,height]. To make it work, you could replace the two last lines of UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords with only one line: self.graph = self.ax.add_patch(rectangle). That way, self.graph.remove() will remove the previously created rectangle.

@JohanC I tried this but the result was still the same

Well, you didn't try it correctly.  Maybe you forgot to remove the last two lines of functino UpdatePlotWithIndicesCoords()? If you'd update your post with the exact code you tried, others can see what needed to change.

Looks like I removed one too many lines that's why it didn't work, my bad. However, replacing the last two line only plotted the last rectangle which is not the solution i wanted. I'll update the post with the solution that worked for me which was just to assign the graph to the self.ax.add_patch(rectangle)

In that case, you also need to remove the line self.graph.remove(). That line doesn't make sense if you only want to add things.

Yes, I noticed. I did some clean-up in my code and it works fine with your initial solution now. I don't know if I should update the post with the changes i made though. Thanks a bunch for your help. Kind regards

As explained by @JohanC, the >=4 lines appear because Axes.plot(*args, ...) is treating the rectangles (which is a list of 4-tuple elements) as a list of sequences to be plotted. You can visualize it with this minimal reproducible code :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rectangles = [
    (-4.8, -4.5, 0.4, 0.2),
    (-4.6, -4.0, 0.8, 0.4),
    (-4.4, -3.5, 1.2, 0.6),
    (-4.2, -3.0, 1.6, 0.8),
    (-4.0, -2.5, 2.0, 1.0),
]

plt.plot(rectangles) # gives exactly 4 lines like OP

The solution is to remove the line below and/or assign the graph to the add_patch call :
self.ax.add_patch(rectangle)

self.graph = self.ax.plot(self.rectangles)[0]
Output (GridDisplayProject> python .\main.py, including a restart) :


thanks a bunch. This fixed it for me. Kind regards
